# get a string of all the variables names and their actual values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a array of variables. I'd like to get a string of all the variables with their variables name and the value it represents. Here is what I have.

```
var date = '1/1/22';
var time = '5:00'
var name = 'some name';
var number = '123-456-7890';

var arr = [date,time,name,number]
```

I'd like to turn it into a string maybe like this:

```
var text = '';
text += arr[0].toUpperCase() + ": " + arr[0] + "\n";
```

which would make `text` output like this in a email body

```
date: 1/1/22
time: 5:00
name: some name
number: 123-456-7890
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? Return from a function? Or output somewhere?

Comment: You can't. Use an object instead: `{date,time,name,number}`.

Comment: *"I have a array of variables."*: you don't. The array has the values, not the variables.

Comment: Simple solution might be 2 parallel arrays: `const names=['date', 'time', 'name', 'number']` and `const values = [date, time, name, number]`. Then you can iterate over them both using the same index and print `names[ii]` and `values[ii]`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox please see edit of question

Comment: So why are you not using an object from the start?

Comment: @jarmod that worked. though might be better if there's a dynamic solution. I can definitely use that for now. thanks!

Comment: @epascarello I'm using the array for other purposes in my code unrelated to the above, hence it was an array. I can reformat it to an object for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**This can not be done with an array** because array items do not have names. The variable **names** are not kept when constructing the array, only their **values**.

It can be done with an object, and then you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate over the contents of the object and get both the key and the value for each item:

```js
var date = '1/1/22';
var time = '5:00'
var name = 'some name';
var number = '123-456-7890';

var obj = { date, time, name, number };

for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
  console.log(key + ": " + value)
```

A final note: the ordering of items as returned by `Object.entries()` is not guaranteed.

---

Another option is to put objects with a single named property into an array. This way the ordering of items is guaranteed, and item names are available using Object.keys():

```js
var date = '1/1/22';
var time = '5:00'
var name = 'some name';
var number = '123-456-7890';

var arr = [ { date }, { time }, { name }, { number } ];

for (var item of arr) {
  // We have knowledge that every object has only 1 property, get its name:
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  console.log(key + ": " + item[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference between arrays and objects. I realize I can't do what I intended with arrays, but this solution is not dynamic and if I understand correctly I would have to hardcode the names. Once I'm there I can use @jarmod idea (in comments of question). I was looking for a way to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use a 2-dimensional array. Here is a code snippet (I copied this from a MacBook, so hopefully it formats ok):

```
        function getVarAndValArray() {

        var date = '1/1/22';
        var time = '5:00'
        var name = 'some name';
        var number = '123-456-7890';

        //Create two-dimensional array
        let arr = [];
        arr[0] = [];    //date
        arr[1] = [];    //time
        arr[2] = [];    //name
        arr[3] = [];    //number
        //-----------------------------------

        //Insert variables names and values
        //Date
        arr[0][0] = 'date';         //variable
        arr[0][1] = '1/1/22';       //value
        //Time
        arr[1][0] = 'time';         //variable
        arr[1][1] = '5:00';         //value
        //Name
        arr[2][0] = 'name';         //variable
        arr[2][1] = 'some name';    //value
        //Number
        arr[3][0] = 'number';       //variable
        arr[3][1] = '123-456-7890'; //value
        //------------------------------------

        return arr;
    }

    //Output the results
    var arr = getVarAndValArray();
    var text = '';
    text += arr[0][0].toUpperCase() + ": " + arr[0][1] + "\n";
    text += arr[1][0].toUpperCase() + ": " + arr[1][1] + "\n";
    text += arr[2][0].toUpperCase() + ": " + arr[2][1] + "\n";
    text += arr[3][0].toUpperCase() + ": " + arr[3][1] + "\n";
    alert(text);
```